# Grunt uglify throws parse error when string started with ` character

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am running grunt uglify task to minify my js files but it is giving me error when string started with ` character.

My string look like this

```
var html = `<div class='list-item'>
              <span>ABC</span>
           </div>`;
```

My Gruntfile.js uglifyjs block is like this

```
uglify: {
  'dev': {
       options: {
          mangle: false
       },
       files: {
          'common/utility_functions.js': ['common/utility_functions.js']
       }
   }
}
```

It is giving me following error when i run grunt uglify

```
>> Uglifying source common/utility_functions.js failed.
   Warning: Uglification failed.
   SyntaxError: Unexpected character '`'.
   Line 162 in common/utility_functions.js
   Use --force to continue.
```

Can anyone help to fix this issue? I think using ` character is valid. It has not given me error during jshint process, because i added enext: true in jshint options.

Answer (score 12):

#### EDIT: Updated Answer 2

The [grunt-contrib-uglify-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-uglify-es) version has now been published to npm. It’s the same *harmony* branch on GitHub that I mentioned in my previous updated answer below. However, it can be installed directly via npm running the following command:

```
npm i -D grunt-contrib-uglify-es
```

---

#### EDIT: Updated Answer

Since answering this question a [harmony](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/tree/harmony) branch of `grunt-contrib-uglify` has been made available. This version handles the [ES6 Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and other ES6 syntax features.

**Installing the *harmony* branch of `grunt-contrib-uglify`:**

1. Firstly uninstall the current version of `grunt-contrib-uglify` by running the following command via your CLI:

   ```
   npm un -D grunt-contrib-uglify
   ```
2. Next install the harmony branch by running:

   ```
   npm i -D https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify.git#harmony
   ```

   *(Note the `harmony` branch in not available via the npm registry so we install it directly via GitHub)*
3. Your `package.json` will now include the following snippet:

   ```json
   ...
   "devDependencies": {
       ...
       "grunt-contrib-uglify-es": "git+https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify.git#harmony"
       ...
   }
   ...
   ```
4. Run your `uglify` Task as per normal, and you will not encounter the error message.

---

#### Original Answer

Your string utilizes the [ES6 Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax and this feature is not supported by [uglify-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) (the JavaScript parser/mangler/compressor used by `grunt-contrib-uglify`).

See the answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429567/some-es6-features-are-not-understood-by-grunt-uglify-js) for further info.

If your project requires the use of ES6 features, then consider transpiling your code, using a JavaScript transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), then uglifying the resultant ES5 code using `grunt-contrib-uglify`.

Alternatively, if ES6 Template Literals are the only part of the ES6 syntax that your project uses, there's always the option of reverting to the older syntax instead for your strings. E.g.

```js
var html = '<div class=\'list-item\'' +
              '<span>ABC</span>' +
           '</div>';
```

The example code shown above will be handled successfully by `grunt-contrib-uglify`.

Comment: grunt-contrib-uglify-es is deprecated

Comment: Same problem still exists in `grunt-contrib-uglify v5.0.0`. Check out [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625390/grunt-contrib-uglify-unexpected-token-string-xxxx-expected-punc).