# Unexpected token: operator (!)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Getting error while crating build in process of js file minifying.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure but i think its related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429567/some-es6-features-are-not-understood-by-grunt-uglify-js .
How to fix for ember-cli.

Comment: Did you try using a linter on your app folder? Did this start happening after a recent code change?

Comment: before version was ember 1.8.0 now i am upgrading to ember 2.8.0

Comment: I would recommend checking an upgrade guide, since you have upgraded a major version. I would guess your package.json has an issue, either with a dependency version or a build command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting error because of minifyJs old version.
I updated minifyJs to latest version, now its working fine.